# Simple custom allocator for block memory?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, memory-management, allocation

Firstly I am not sure if there may be a simpler way to do this (see the end of my message)....

I would like to write a custom allocator which ensures that my heap-allocated objects are stored in continuous memory. How simple would this be, say, to allocate 1GB on the heap and then assign (on a first come first serve basis) 1000 bytes to each object?

I thought the simpler way may be to declare an array (continuous memory) and store the objects inside that. Which technique would have the better performance?

(I am thinking about loading a cache-line full of the objects and trying to minimise cache misses)

Comment: Why not just put all your objects in e.g. a `std::vector` ?

Comment: Those sound like the same technique to me, just dressed up differently. An array vs. a custom allocator backed by an array.

Comment: @StephanvandenHeuvel if the two aren't the same, which one is best-performing and if its a custom allocator, how would you implement this?

Comment: @user997112 If you allocate an array with new char[1GB]; or use a global char [1GB] , there is little difference. Performance will be in the algorithm you find and hand out memory from those arrays. What you should also take care of is handing out suitable aligned memory for whatever you use that memory for

Comment: Why do you want "objects are stored in continuous memory"?

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a [pool allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool).
You can implement using a [free list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list).